# I'm making a beginner level OCR app and im stuck

Tags: javascript, html, ocr

I'm following along a tutorial i'm watching on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1I3tcALTlc) and the .png files i'm converting don't seem to be saving in my uploads file. I've been looking over my code to see if there is even the smallest significant difference, but I haven't found one. I really hope someone can help me

the javascript code:

```
//We declared all our imports
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer');
const {TesseractWorker} = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = new TesseractWorker();

//Storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('avatar');

app.set('view engine', "ejs");

//Routes

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/upload', (req ,res) => {
    upload(req ,res, err => {
        console.log(req.file);
    });
});

//Start Up our server

const PORT = 5000 || process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Hey I'm running on port ${PORT}`));
```

and the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Img to PDF</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Image to PDF</h1>
      <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" />
        <button type="submit">Convert</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the package.json file, if that makes a difference:

```
{
  "name": "ocr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "tesseract.js": "^2.0.0-alpha.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an insignificant difference? Maybe it is not so insignificant as you think.

Comment: the only differences are the quotation marks (instead of putting " ", i put ' ' at certain parts)